# "Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated" what does this mean?

Tags: command-line, php, magento

Every command I run on Ubuntu 18.04 seems to return this error:

```
Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated.
This message will be suppressed on further calls in
/var/www/vhosts/nuovamoda.gr/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
on line 81
```

[Screenshot of commands](http://prntscr.com/kv28nb)

Possibly relatedly, I have in plesk php version 7.0 but in CLI [I see 7.2](http://prntscr.com/kv297k)
Any suggest?

Comment: Tell us more about your system (Ubuntu version, what did you install? ) - and please don't post screenshots of text - [edit] your question and paste that text.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 i have plesk panel with php 7.0 was php 7.2 magento installed with php 7.0 but my CLI shows me php version 7.2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of text output. Copy and paste from terminal into the **original question** using the **[Edit Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1075799/edit)**. and format the text output as `code` using the {_} icon **above the edit question window**.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated.
> This message will be suppressed on further calls in
> /var/www/vhosts/nuovamoda.gr/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
> on line 81
> ```

That's not an *error*.  It's a *warning* that `each()` will disappear in *some future version* (which is what deprecation means in software).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

> While **a deprecated software feature remains in the software**, its use may raise warning messages recommending alternative practices; deprecated status may also indicate the feature will be removed in the future. Features are deprecated rather than immediately removed, to provide backward compatibility, and to give programmers time to bring affected code into compliance with the new standard.

Comment: as i see 18.4 works with 7.2 php version so i have to downgrade to 16.4 again

Comment: @darkattack nothing in your question says that the program doesn't work.

Comment: well i have troubles with php versions... :S plesk panel shows me 7.0 version of php cli shows me 7.2

Comment: @darkattack then the mismatched versions are your problem, not the deprecation warning.

Comment: yes i just reinstalled 16.4 will see what will shows me now ...